# Convert Date To ToShortDateString In Razor

Tags: razor

i have a DateTime Field that must be shown in Edit view

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.StartDate )
```

how can i use somthing like this ;

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.StartDate.ToShortDateString() )
```

or any custom function for changing the DateTime for view.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute on your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

and then in your view simply:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
```

Comment: it works! I copied your example and then I noticed I was using textboxfor - not sure why it doesn't work on that. thanks

Comment: This is great. There are so many attributes/tags that I don't know about.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this

```
<td>
    @{ 
       var date = item.PostDate.ToShortDateString();
     }
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => date)
</td>
```