# Limit the number of characters displayed

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do i limit the number of characters diplayed.

Here is my code from my cshtml file

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)
```

All Help Appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can write a helper method like this in the Utility class and import in the Razor page or add in the web.config . You can read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb383977.aspx

```
       public static string DisplayText(this string str , int charallowed){
            if(str.Length > charallowed)
                   return str.Substring(0,charallowed) + " ...." ;
            return str;
        }

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TextDisplayText(20));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, do i put the method in the controller and the:
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => DisplayText(item.Text,20)); 
in the .cshtml file? @Devesh

Comment: You can create extension for the string class. I have updated the my code.

Comment: I like the solution, but it throws an error, same example as someone else posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754071/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension