# TextBoxFor decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my database I stored fields with the data type `decimal`. I am using exactly the same (`decimal`) data type in my ASP.NET application.

This is inside my view in order to display the value.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Stock, new { id = "Stock", @class = "k-textbox" })
```

This pretty straight forward. The only issue I am facing is that by default in my view the data is displayed with 4 decimal places.

I give you a few examples on how it looks and how it should look:

> 1. 1,0000 => 1
> 2. 1,2000 => 1,2
> 3. 1,4300 => 1,43
> 4. 1,8920 => 1,892
> 5. 1,5426 => 1,5426

As you can see I want to cut off all the `0` as decimal places (only when displayed in the view).

Remember: I am using commas instead of decimal points.

**Edit:**

My model

```
public class Article
{
    public decimal? Stock{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not related but `new { id = "Stock" }` is pointless - the method already generates it. You can use one of the overloads which accepts a `DataFormatString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{0:G29}` like this:

```
@{
    string temp = string.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse(Model.Stock.ToString()));
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => temp)
}
```

Or with string interpolation:

```
@{
    string temp = $"{decimal.Parse(Model.Stock.ToString()):G29}";
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => temp)
}
```

**EDIT:**
The reason that you can't get the value in your `Controller` after you save it is that the model binder can't find a property with name `temp`. You can use a `TextBox` instead of `TextBoxFor` to solve this issue like this:

```
string temp = $"{decimal.Parse(Model.Stock.ToString()):G29}";
@Html.TextBox("Stock" , temp)
```

Or if you still want to use `TextBoxFor` you can just rename the `temp` variable to `Stock`:

```
string Stock = string.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse(Model.Stock.ToString()));
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Stock)
```

Comment: Thanks that looks pretty good, but it gives me the error conversion from decima? in strang not possible.

Comment: This works but I have to put a .ToString() at the end of it. Like: decimal.Parse(Model.Stock.ToString())

Comment: I can use it like this: string temp = $"{Model.Bestand:G29}";

Comment: In my model it already is decimal not a string so I don't have to parse it, right?

Comment: There is a problem though. If I save it, it doesn't take the value. I am pretty sure that is because it isn't hooked up anymore. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @Anokrize OK. The reason is that the model binder can't find a property with name `temp`. I've provided the solution for that. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Anokrize And if you still want to use `TextBoxFor` you can just rename the `temp` variable to `Stock`.

Comment: Great, did it!!

Comment: Why do you convert to string, then to decimal and finally to string with 2 places again using string.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse(Model.Stock.ToString())); ? Why not to simple use directly string.Format("{0:G29}", Model.Stock); or Model.Stock.ToString("G29") ? Is not the same? I think so

Answer (score 8):

The `G29` argument of the `string.Format` method does exactly what you want.

You can use the the following attribute on your models `Stock` value.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:G29}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Or you can use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_9) which @Chris mentioned.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Stock, "{0:G29}", new { id = "Stock", @class = "k-textbox" })
```

Comment: But the data type is decimal in my model. Isn't the displayformat for strings? I made an edit of my post.

Comment: And the overload method "G29" has to be in front of the custom css.

Comment: These two methods seem like a very good approach. I would like to use it in my code. Thanks!! I just don't know how to use the displayformat as it doesn't change someting. I guess it is because it is not a string?

Comment: the overload method doesn't change something. It looks still the same as before.

Comment: See this post, thats the error I get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754071/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension

Comment: I think there is only the solution as S. Akbari said although it doesn't look very clean.

Comment: @Anokrize hm strange that the second doesn't work. Did you try the latest one? I would consider using the view model as the accepted answer of the question you posted here sugessted.

Comment: Yeah I tried it but it doesn't work.... Really strange. It doesn't give me an error but it doesn't change something.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [overload of `TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) that takes a `format` parameter that it uses to format the text.

This will allow you to format your number in any way you want.