# Asp.NET MVC Razor Format Decimal? to #.###,##

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application.

I try to render a property from my model as a correct numeric value:

The property in the ViewModel:

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

the data from the DB looks like this: *99999,99*

My desired format would look like this: **99.999,99**

In my razor View I use the property like this:

```
@Model.Price
```

Unfortunately it looks still like this: *99999.99*

Do you know how I can format that *decimal?* value correctly on my view?

Is there also a solution without using a display template?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059438/2946329

Comment: Does it have to be a textbox.for?

Comment: You can try it, for `EditorFor` I think you should use a template.

Comment: `@Model.Price.ToString("#.##")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using String Format to show decimal up to 2 places or simple integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-up-to-2-places-or-simple-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Try Using This Guide**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class TestClass
{
     public static void Main()
     {
         int i = 100;

         // Creates a CultureInfo for English in Belize.
         CultureInfo bz = new CultureInfo("en-BZ");
         // Displays i formatted as currency for the bz.
         Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", bz));

         // Creates a CultureInfo for English in the U.S.
         CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
         // Display i formatted as currency for us.
         Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", us));

         // Creates a CultureInfo for Danish in Denmark.
         CultureInfo dk = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
         // Displays i formatted as currency for dk.
         Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", dk));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
decimal value = 99999.99M;
string display = value.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es"));
```

Displays

> 99.999,99

I have tried all the values below:

`"C"` is used for displaying currency in your culture

`"C2"` currency with two digits after decimal point

`"C2", culture`: I'm using a culture which decimal point is comma

`"N2", culture`: Because I want to show only number, without currency symbol

Comment: Hi Thank you! I now use this in my razor view:

Comment: @String.Format("{0:N0}", @Model.PreisVon)