# How to manipulate item value in view whithout model value manipulation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I just started learning ASP.Net MVC, I'm trying to change my previous code (which was based on WebForm) to MVC but I encounter an Issue, Imagine I'm working on article to show a list of it:

Here is the Model:

```
public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is part of View:

```
<span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime )</span>
```

I wrote a method in controller to change Geregrian date to Persian date:

```
public string ConvertToPersianDate(object date)
        {
            clsWorkWithDate wwd = new clsWorkWithDate();
            date = wwd.gregorianToShamsi(Convert.ToDateTime(date));
            return date.ToString();
        }
```

Now I want to get access this function in view, something like this:

```
@ConvertToPersianDate(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime ))
```

But the error message says that `ConvertToPersianDate` does not exist in the current context, it seems it's not accessible in view.

I had no problem when it was in WebForm list view:

```
<%#  ConvertToPersianDate(Eval("CreationDateTime")) %>
```

How can I resolve the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function should be static.

```
public static string ConvertToPersianDate(object date)
{
    clsWorkWithDate wwd = new clsWorkWithDate();
    date = wwd.gregorianToShamsi(Convert.ToDateTime(date));
    return date.ToString();
}
```

Then you can use the function like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => YourAppName.Controllers.YourControllerName.ConvertToPersianDate(item.CreationDateTime) )
```

You can shorten this by adding an using at the top of the view.

```
@using YourAppName.Controllers
…
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => YourControllerName.ConvertToPersianDate(item.CreationDateTime) )
```

EDIT

This should work fine.

```
@YourAppName.Controllers.YourControllerName.ConvertToPersianDate(item.CreationDateTime)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error message in run time: `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions`. it has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754071/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension).

Comment: Oh, forgot that. Are you just displaying the date? You can just drop the DisplayFor then. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, that's exactly what I was looking for, anyway, is it the recommended approach?

Comment: I would probably create an extension method so that I could shorten it to @item.CreationDateTime.ToPersianDate()

Comment: As for your answer, `item` is valid if it's in `@foreach (var item in Model)`, what if it's a single instance of model (not in `@foreach`), in that case VS says `item` does not exist.

Comment: I found the answer, it should be: `@YourAppName.Controllers.YourControllerName.ConvertToPersianDate(Model.CreationDateTime)` then. (Uppercase M in Model)