# Format Date When Using DisplayFor HTML Tag Helper

Tags: c#, razor, tag-helpers

My development environment consists of ASP .Net Core 2.2 Razor (non-MVC), using c#

On one of my .cshtml files I am using the following code to display information in a table:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate.ToLongDateString())
```

StartDate is saved as a DateTime field in the database.

According to the Microsoft Docs, .ToLongDateString() should format the date as follows:  "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"

However, I am getting the following error on the field:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with
>   field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or
>   single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Any information on how to correctly format StartDate would be appreciated.

Comment: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754071/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension). Another user had a similar error and his solution may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to format the date using this code in my Class (.cs) file:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode =true, DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```