# concatenating strings in razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am trying to concatenate strings firstname and lastname in my model. When I run my project I get an error that reads....*

> InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field
> access, property access, single-dimension array index, or
> single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

- 

Here is the line of code that is giving me the error.

```
<input asp-for="@(Model.ContactPersonName + "" + @Model.ContactPersonSurname)" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: I think you'd need to create a FullName property on your model that does the concatenation because `for` expects a single field/property...  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754071/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set value with `@(Model.ContactPersonName + "" + @Model.ContactPersonSurname)`,you can use `value=...`.`asp-for`  extracts the name of the specified model property into the rendered HTML. And it can only extract one model property.

```
<input value="@(Model.ContactPersonName + "" + @Model.ContactPersonSurname)" class="form-control" />
```