# Replace item returned with image

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to replace the text of an item returned from my model with an image. Is there an easy way to just define the "replace" on the view? Something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item2.Replace("s","myImageHere.png")) <---Image Here----
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item4)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**EDIT**: I should have added the exception being thrown:

> InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: The error is fixed if you use a property `get` to return the value replaced. In your model create this property `public string Item2Image { get { return Item2.Replace("s", "myImageHere.png"); }}` This question is a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754071/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension and there are different solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: (although I would use CSS for the style) - perhaps put a `get{}` in the model to keep it cleaner that returns a path, perhaps even all of it.

```
 @{
    var imgURLVal = item.Item2.Replace("s","myImageHere.png"); 
  }
  <img src="~/Content/img/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>imgURLVal)" style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>
```

Comment: This gives me the same exception I was getting above unfortunately "InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: I still recommend the model change but I will update with one possible view only change.