# get MM/dd/yyyy only in razor for datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, razor

I have something code like this

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded)
```

and working fine. But It is retrieving the whole data from my sql

**Output from current code**

`3/22/2017 12:00:00 AM`

**Desired output**

`3/22/2017`

I try to use a code like this `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded.Value.ToShortDateString())` but it gives me an error

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

I try to search on google and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639052/convert-date-to-toshortdatestring-in-razor) but for me its a long method? And I am new in that method so I don't know how to use it.

Is there any shortest way to achieve the desired output?.

> **Update**

**Controller code**

```
PersonVoluntaryWork pvw = db.PersonVoluntaryWorks.Single(vw => vw.VoluntaryWorksId == id);
return PartialView("_NewPersonVoluntaryWorks", pvw);
```

> **View**

```
@model System.Models.PersonVoluntaryWork
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <td>
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded)       
</td>
 }
```

Comment: You can also use ToShortDateString() at the end like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded.ToShortDateString() )

Comment: can you show your model class?

Comment: I would strongly advise that you need to sort out the datetime issue inside your controller (or service class) either as part of the initial HttpGet action to populate the view, or inside the HttpPost when you send the values back. Either way, the remedial action must be taken at controller level.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply a `DisplayFormatAttribute` to your property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateEnded { get; set; }
```

and the format will be respected by the `EditorFor()` method.

Alternatively you can use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, "{0:d}", null)
```

Comment: i try it just now `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, "{0:d}")` but it still return the `. . AM`

Comment: @StephenMuecke looks like you don't need 3rd parameter. `TextBoxFor` has this overload: `public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string format)`

Comment: @teovankot, Yes, your correct - there is an overload for that (not sure why OP is claiming it did not work)

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Fortunatly `EditorFor` hepler doesn't have this overload. that's why you should use `TextBoxFor` html helper

**Update:**

MVC 3 doesn't have this overload. So the simpliest way to solve your problem will be use not strongly typed helper like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("VoluntaryWork_DateEnded", 
    Model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded.HasValue
    ? Model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    : DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: See edit. I include codes. I also try your suggested code but its still the same.

Comment: @KiRa what version of MVC do you use?

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` :D explain a bit the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138705/discussion-between-kira-and-teo-van-kot).

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your property in the model like this:

**[DataType(DataType.Date)]

public DateTime? DateEnded{ get; set; }**

It will hide the time from your dateEnded property.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this code**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded, 
    new { @Value = model.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") })
```

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods!

Comment: You can set value attribute when using HtmlHelper because I can use my projects.

Comment: Then your doing the wrong thing and it means you will never get true 2-way model binding. The method correctly sets the value based on (in order) `ModelState` values, `ViewData` values and finally the model value.

Answer (score -1):

**To add a property to your model add this code:**

```
public string ReturnDateForDisplay  
{  
    get  
    {  
       return this.VoluntaryWork.DateEnded.ToString("d");  
    }  
}
```

**Then in your PartialView:**

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDateForDisplay)`

Comment: I have modified the answer, please go through it.

Comment: It won't bind on POST, dude