# Trying to convert DateTime to ShortDateString in razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

Currently my DateTime gets displayed as this in my view example: 03/08/2017 00:00:00. I want it to be displayed as follow: 03/08/2017 without the time being displayed. This is my current view code

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeSpent) hr
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Task.Name)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.IdTimeSheet_Details }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.IdTimeSheet_Details }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.IdTimeSheet_Details })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

What i have tried so far:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth.Value.ToString("dd. MM. yyyy"))
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty))
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth.Value.ToString("dd - M - yy"))
```

None of the above has worked. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?
The exeption im getting is

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions

But i dont really see what im doing differently from the people in the posts below:

[Where i got most of the things i have tried from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

[Other post i have checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944837/get-mm-dd-yyyy-only-in-razor-for-datetime)

Comment: [Converting DateTime format using razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use just

```
<td>item.DayOfMonth.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</td>
```

or if you want to use `DisplayFor()`, then apply a

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public DateTime DayOfMonth { get; set; }
```

to your property and in the view

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayOfMonth)</td>
```

Comment: Jup the above code worked. Thank you. Going to approve when it lets me